# Draw lines at angles-Processing

Tags: rotation, drawing, line, processing

How do I draw lines at 30 degrees to each other using processing? I have read the [2D-Transformation](http://www.processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) page but I do not want to rotate the grid, I just want to draw the lines at 30 degrees to each other. How do I do so?

I am including a sample image below, sorry for the terrible drawing with paint (didn't want to use processing), how do I go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple trig maybe?

```java
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  PVector center = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
  for (int i = 360; i >= 180; i-=30) {
    float x = center.x + cos(radians(i))*50;
    float y = center.y + sin(radians(i))*50;
    line(center.x, center.y, x, y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following program generates a random unit vector *input* and returns a *output* vector  rotated *outputShift* radians clockwise. If you want counterclockwise rotation, just use negative values.

```java
PVector input, output;
float inputAngle, outputShift, radius;

void setup () {
  size(500, 500);
  load();
}

void draw () {
  background(255);

  translate(width/2, height/2);

  ellipse (0, 0, radius*2, radius*2);

  line(0, 0, input.x, input.y);
  line(0, 0, output.x, output.y);
}

void load () {
  input = PVector.random2D();

  inputAngle = atan2(input.y, input.x);
  outputShift = PI/6; 

  output = new PVector (
  cos(inputAngle+outputShift), 
  sin(inputAngle+outputShift)
    );

  radius = 200;

  input.setMag(radius);
  output.setMag(radius);
}

void keyReleased () {
  load();
}
```